# Getting table information for Redshift `stl_load_errors` errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift COPY command to load data into Redshift table from S3. When something goes wrong, I typically get an error `ERROR:  Load into table 'example' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details`. I can always lookup `stl_load_errors` manually to get details. Now, I am trying to figure out how I can do that automatically.

From [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) it looks like the following query should give me all the details I need:

```
SELECT *
FROM stl_load_errors errors
INNER JOIN svv_table_info info
  ON errors.tbl = info.table_id
    AND info.schema = '<schema-name>'
    AND info.table = '<table-name>'
```

However it always returns nothing. I also tried using `stv_tbl_perm` instead of `svv_table_info`, and still nothing.

After some troubleshooting, I see two things I don't understand:

1. I see multiple different IDs in `stv_tbl_perm` and `svv_table_info` for the same exact table. Why is that?
2. I see `tbl` filed on `stl_load_errors` referencing ids that do not exist in `stv_tbl_perm` or `svv_table_info`. Again why?

Feels like I don't understanding something in structure of these tables, but it completely escapes me what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of it, and it is surprisingly boring and probably not useful to many ...

I had an existing table. My code that was creating the table was wrapped in transaction, and it was dropping the table inside the transaction. The code that was querying the `stl_load_errors` was outside the transaction. So the `table_id` outside and inside the transaction where different, as it was a different table.

Comment: This basically was happening for me because I was using integer in the table schema but the data in the s3 was in text form. When I converted the field to varchar as well in the table definition. It is just an FYI. So to solve this issue, either correct the schema/ tweak the table definition a bit.

Answer (score 8):

This is because tbl and table_id are with different types. First one is integer, second one is **[iod](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-oid.html)**.

When you cast iod to integer the columns have the same values. You could check this query:

```
SELECT table_id::integer, table_id
FROM SVV_TABLE_INFO
```

I have result when I execute

```
SELECT errors.tbl, info.table_id::integer, info.table_id, *
FROM stl_load_errors errors
INNER JOIN svv_table_info info
  ON errors.tbl = info.table_id
```

Please note that inner join is `ON errors.tbl = info.table_id`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference in types. However, running your query still gives no results for me. In fact I don't see how your join is any different than my join in the question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Even that the types are different you could do the join on errors.tbl = info.table_id.

You could try to do 2 single queries. One "SELECT table_id::integer
FROM SVV_TABLE_INFO" and another one with "select tbl from stl_load_errors". And you could see if there is any match (manually).

I am using SQL Workbench/J and I am able to do "INNER JOIN" on "ON errors.tbl = info.table_id" and actually I have results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking by filename. Doesn't really answer the question about joining the various tables, but I use a query like so to group up files that are part of the same manifest file and let me compare it to the `maxerror` setting:

```
select min(starttime) over (partition by substring(filename, 1, 53)) as starttime,
    substring(filename, 1, 53) as filename, btrim(err_reason) as err_reason, count(*)
from stl_load_errors where filename like '%/some_s3_path/%' 
group by starttime, filename, err_reason order by starttime desc;
```

This worked for me without any casting:

```
schemaz=# select i.database, e.err_code from stl_load_errors e join svv_table_info i on e.tbl=i.table_id limit 5
schemaz-# ;
database  | err_code
-----------+----------
schemaz |     1204
schemaz |     1204
schemaz |     1204
schemaz |     1204
schemaz |     1204
```